# How can i fix this error in python bot code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I have same error in python code when i start code

I try write telegram bot with python-telegram-bot

This is my code :

```
from telegram.ext import Updater , CommandHandler , CallbackContext
from telegram import Update
from telegram.chataction import ChatAction


#bot API
token = "*********:*************" #Im hide API

#bot commands and messages
messages_and_commands = {
    "start" : "Hello {} {} wellcome to my bot !"
}
def start_bot(update : Update , context : CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
    last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
    context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id , action = ChatAction)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id , text=messages_and_commands["start"].format(first_name , last_name))

#bot to can start in the telegram
updater = Updater(token=token , use_context=True)
#set command handler
start_robot = CommandHandler('start' , start_bot)
#add dispatcher
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_robot)
#start polling to while start
updater.start_polling()
#when i use ctrl+c the bot is finish action in telegram
updater.idle()
```

And this is my error in when i start bot:

```
    No error handlers are registered, logging exception.                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py",      `line 432, in process_update`                                                                                             
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line `156, in handle_update`
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "telegram_bot.py", line 16, in start_bot
    context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id , action = ChatAction)
  File "<decorator-gen-20>", line 2, in send_chat_action
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 135, in `decorator`
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 1880, in `send_chat_action`
    result = self._post('sendChatAction', data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 245, in `_post`
    return self.request.post(f'{self.base_url}/{endpoint}', data=data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/hsahfodsauhfda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", `line       352, in post`
    body=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
  TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out the code you pasted here locally. Indeed, once I launch the bot and call the "start" handler I get the same error.

If we have a closer look at the error message we can see this line from your code:

```
context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id , action = ChatAction)
```

According to [the docs, telegram.ChatAction](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chataction.html#telegram-chataction) is a "class to provide constants for different chat actions.", hence if you wish to reference a ChatAction you need to explicitly mention one, like `ChatAction.TYPING`.

So in your case, if you use the `send_chat_action` function like this:

```
context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)
```

You should not get the error.

Let me know if it helped!